# Are there non-quantum, (potentially) realizable in the real world models of computation that allow a polynomial speedup over RAM?

Tags: computation-models

I hear a lot about how quantum computers are a big thing because they allow solving some problems in polynomial time which we don't know how to do classically. As far as I understand it still isn't fully proven that they can be built in a scalable way. But what about less dramatic speedups? Could we build a computer that could, for example, find out the longest common subsequence of two strings in linear time or multiply matrices in $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ time? Is there some physical/metaphysical significance to the RAM model or is it just whatever people first came up with?

Sorry in advance for any false assumptions and problems this question might have, I hope that at least something can be extracted from it that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps. Nobody knows.